# Возможно ли установить временное ограничение на использование команды?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

Можно ли поставить ограничение на использование команды? Одно использование на 3 дня к примеру? Нужна может какая-то библиотека?

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Создайте базу данных и при использовании команды записывайте в БД id юзера и дату последнего использования. А также добавьте в обработку команды логику, которая будет доставать из этой БД дату последнего использования, проверять, что она старше, чем 3 дня и в случае если это не так, возвращайте пользователю соответствующее сообщение.

Comment: У меня с БД без того проблемы, есть ли что-то попроще?

Comment: @dust куда уж проще

Comment: оке, просто я не могу найти нормальное обьяснение. Ну или я просто не вижу